# Regex to extract text from a pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string pattern, which contains a ID and Text to make markup easier for our staff.

The pattern to create a "fancy" button in our CMS is:

> (button_section_ID:TEXT)

**Example**:

> (button_section_25:This is a fancy button)

How do I extract the "This is a fancy button" part of that pattern? The pattern will always be the same. I tried to do some substring stuff but that got  complicated very fast.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Substringing got  complicated? Maybe because you first need to trim `(` and `)`.

Comment: use `String.Split` on `:`, then trim off the closing brace at the end.

Comment: @Baldrick The thing is in C#, I can NEVER know what the TEXT is gonna be. So I can't just do a String.Split on the whole example, as I only know the button_section_ID part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the text is always in the format you specified, you just need to trim parentheses and then split with `:`:

```
var res = input.Trim('(', ')').Split(':')[1];
```

If the string is a substring, use a regex:

```
var match = Regex.Match(input, @"\(button_section_\d+:([^()]+)\)");
var res = match.Success ? match.Groups[1].Value : "";
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C(button_section_%5Cd%2B%3A(%5B%5E()%5D%2B)%5C)&i=(button_section_25%3AThis%20is%20a%20fancy%20button)%0D%0AText%20here%20(button_section_135%3AThis%20is%20a%20another%20fancy%20button)).

[image]

**Explanation:**

- `\(button_section_` - a literal `(button_section_`
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `:`  -  a colon
- `([^()]+)` - Group 1 capturing 1+ characters other than `(` and `)` (you may replace with `([^)]*)`  to make matching safer and allow an empty string and `(` inside this value)
- )`- a literal`)`

Comment: I have added some explanations. Note that `[^()]+` does not allow an empty string and `(` from `(` till `)`. Replace with `[^)]*` to match empty strings and `(` in between the `(` and first `)`.

Answer (score 0):

The following .NET regex will give you a match containing a group with the text you want:

```
var match = Regex.Matches(input, @"\(button_section_..:(.*)\)");
```

The braces define a match group, which will give you everything between the button section, and the final curly brace.